# Bring to front labels in array in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, label, picturebox

I created an array of labels that I am trying to display on a picturebox that has a picture of a game board. I keep displaying the labels behind the picturebox and am not sure what I'm doing wrong.

```
public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int x = 100;
        int y = 0;

        // create 361 labels, set their dimensions
        for (int i = 0; i < 361; i++)
        {
            board[i] = new Label();
            board[i].Parent = pictureBox1;
            board[i].Location = new Point(x, y);
            board[i].Name = "label" + i;
            board[i].Width = 55;
            board[i].Height = 55;
            board[i].Text = "0";
            board[i].BackColor = Color.Black;
            board[i].BringToFront();

        }


        // set the position of the label
        foreach (Label i in board)
        {
            if (x >= 580)
            {
                x = 0;
                y = y + i.Height + 55;
            }

            i.Location = new Point(x, y);
            this.Controls.Add(i);
            x += i.Width;
        }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Move the call to `BringToFront` AFTER having added the labels to the forms container

```
// set the position of the label
foreach (Label i in board)
{
    if (x >= 580)
    {
        x = 0;
        y = y + i.Height + 55;
    }

    i.Location = new Point(x, y);
    this.Controls.Add(i);
    i.BringToFront();
    x += i.Width;
}
```

By the way, not a big gain, but you could put this code inside the first loop and remove the foreach loop

Comment: Perfect that works! Can you explain why that is? Still confused by it wouldn't bring the labels to front from within the for loop.

Comment: BringToFront alters the z index (the depth) at which you control is positioned in respect to the other controls. When you add the controls to the form container the z index is recalculated and your previous BringToFront call becomes useless. You could also try to use SendToBack on the PictureBox avoiding the call to BringToFront for each Label. (Need to test it)